# SQL Server Orthography

Tags: sql-server, directory

I notice that most of the Microsoft SQL Server installations have a '**Binn**' folder, e.g.

```
\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn
```

This has always bugged me. Is this merely a misspelled abbreviation for binary? Perhaps it is related to the [village in the Swiss Alps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binn)? Any ideas? :)

Comment: interesting question, but probably not the place to get is answered!

Comment: I have a C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Bin as well as a C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **BINN** directory was originally for the 32bit utilities and the **BIN** directory was for 16bit utilities.

Microsoft is slowly reclaiming the **BIN** directory though.

Comment: And N'string' is for unicode. So, I guess an extraneous N always means "one more order-of-magnitude than you are used to."

Comment: I'm looking for a copy of SQL Server 6.5 or earlier so I can get a file list of the BIN vs. BINN directory.  I know I still have a copy somewhere.  I will probably need to install NT 4 as well.  Should be an interesting little project.